# How to get data from dynamo db based on List of String (ProductId) and this product id is [DynamoDBGlobalSecondaryIndexHashKey]

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I used below code to retrieve the data by passing list of productIds from dyanamo db. and my productId is [DynamoDBGlobalSecondaryIndexHashKey] GSI not the primary key.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetProductListWithMissingTransportMissionAsync(IEnumerable<string> listProductId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            var availableProductId =  new List<string>();
            foreach (var productId in listProductId)
            {
                var items = await _context.QueryAsync<TransportMissionDb>(productId,
                new DynamoDBOperationConfig()
                {
                    OverrideTableName = _tableName,
                    IndexName = "TransportMissionProductIdIndex"
                }).GetRemainingAsync(cancellationToken);
                if(items.Count > 0)
                    availableProductId.Add(items.FirstOrDefault().ProductId);
            }
           return listProductId.Except(availableProductId).ToList();
        }
```

But the problem is _Context(IDynamoDBContext) will be called based on the productIds count (multiple times). How to optimize this?

Comment: What exactly is the question? It seems like an x/y problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer after multiple read and try.. We can use Parallel call.

`public async Task<IEnumerable> GetProductListWithMissingTransportMissionAsync(IEnumerable listProductId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
{
var availableProductId = new List();

```
        var queryTasks = listProductId.Select(async productId =>
        {
            var items = await _context.QueryAsync<TransportMissionDb>(productId,
                new DynamoDBOperationConfig()
                {
                    OverrideTableName = _tableName,
                    IndexName = "TransportMissionProductIdIndex"
                }).GetRemainingAsync(cancellationToken);

            return (productId, items);
        }).ToList();

        var queryResults = await Task.WhenAll(queryTasks);

        foreach (var (productId, items) in queryResults)
        {
            if (items.Count > 0)
            {
                availableProductId.Add(items.FirstOrDefault().ProductId);
            }
        }

        return listProductId.Except(availableProductId).ToList();
    }`
```